# Namespace qualified names INSIDE a user namespace

Tags: c++

In C++, if I have

```
namespace myNamespace {
    boost::whatever();
}
```

will the compiler look for whatever() in the boost namespace or in myNamespace::boost?

Comment: I don't think you can create a temporary object at namespace scope. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not about whether it will look for `boost::whatever`, but where it will find `boost` *itself*.

If you have a nested namespace definition with the name `boost`, it will *hide* the global `boost` namespace at its point of declaration. The global `boost` namespace will be visible up until the point where `myNamespace::boost` is declared (§3.3.2/2).

> [ Note: a name from an outer scope remains visible up to the point of declaration of the name that hides it. [ Example:
>
> ```c++
> const int i = 2;
> { int i[i]; }
> ```
>
> declares a block-scope array of two integers. — end example ] — end note ]

So if you're calling `boost::whatever()` before the nested name `myNamespace::boost` is created, it will look for the global `boost` namespace. You can qualify the name with `::boost` if you always want it to find `boost` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you mean this:

```
namespace myNamespace {
     using boost::whatever; // NOT boost::whatever();
}
```

Remember that C++ namespaces are mainly to avoid naming clashes not a design mechanism, which means when you are using a method of other namespaces in another one, you just call the original one and there is no copy in new namespace scope. So, when you call `myNamespace::whatever()`, compiler would choose `boost::whatever()` not `myNamespace::boost::whatever()` because there is no `boost` namespace declared inside `myNamespace`.

For more details on namespaces you could see:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to call a function using some qualification, you may end up using a local namespace rather than a global namespace:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A { void f() { std::cout << "::A::f()\n"; } }
namespace B {
    namespace A { void f() { std::cout << "::B::A::f()\n"; } }
    void g() { A::f(); }
    void h() { ::A::f(); }
}

int main() {
    B::g();
    B::h();
}
```

If you want to make sure you are picking up a specific namespace you'll need to use absolute qualification as in `::A::f()`.